# Using this keyword as lock in concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, this, inner-classes

In the following program, does the this keywords in the LoggerThread class refer to LoggerThread object or LogService object? Logically it should refer to LogService in order for the syncronization to work, but semantically it seems it is referring to LoggerThread.

```
public class LogService {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
    private final PrintWriter writer;
    @GuardedBy("this") private boolean isShutdown;
    @GuardedBy("this") private int reservations;
    public void start() { loggerThread.start(); }
    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
        loggerThread.interrupt();
    }
    public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isShutdown)
                throw new IllegalStateException("...");
            ++reservations;
        }
        queue.put(msg);
    }
    private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                        String msg = queue.take();
                        synchronized (this) { --reservations; }
                        writer.println(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ }
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` within `LoggerThread` methods refers to a `LoggerThread` instance.
`LogService.this` refers to the outer class.

---

Both `isShutdown` and `reservations` are synchronised by the different locks (`LoggerThread.this` and `LogService.this`), so `@GuardedBy("this")` doesn't reflect the reality.

Comment: I also think so, then logically I think this program is incorrect, it uses two different locks for syncronizing access to the same boolean object isShutDown.

Comment: @DerekXie, btw, is the annotation used only for the documentation purpose?

Comment: @DerekXie, you're right, both `isShutdown` and `reservations` are synchronised by the different locks (`LoggerThread.this` and `LogService.this`)

Comment: Yes the annotation is only for documentation purpose. The author uses nonstandard annotation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from the great book "Java Concurrency In Practice", Listing 7.15
It is a typo and is mentioned in "Errata" section:
http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/errata.html

Answer (score -1):

`this` refers to the current instance of the immediately enclosing class. [JLS #15.8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4).

> Logically it should refer to LogService in order for the syncronization to work, but semantically it seems it is referring to LoggerThread.

Correct. It's a bug.

Comment: No, it's not a bug.